# Paypal Express Checkout Mobile Responsive with instant update

Tags: paypal, express-checkout, instant, nvp

I'm using the Paypal Express Checkout NVP (Name Value Pair) API. When I add a Callback URL for instant update shipping cost the whole paypal user interface changes to an older version that isn't mobile friendly / responsive.

When I try to force the mobile UI with "_mobile-express-checkout" I'm getting an Error-Message that I'm using an outdated version. But I'm using version 204 that is the most up to date version.

Is there any chance to get the responsive layout together with instant update for shipping cost?

Comment: Unfortunately, I gave up on the instant update API years ago because it just makes things more difficult.  It isn't worth the benefit to me.  Also, the in-context feature for Express Checkout sort takes away the need for instant update, too.  Have you looked into that?

Comment: great to see this. PayPal's UI has been an utter joke for years. It's seriously pathetic and somebody should have been fired over it. https://www.bigcommerce.com/blog/paypal-express-checkout-in-context-one-touch/

Comment: Paypal are zero help and documentation yields no clues, and thankfully  (/sarcasm) they don't make a distinction between non-responsive and responsive version of the checkout you are served #facepalm. Anyway In our testing of this on multiple clean installs of Magento and it seems that the mobile express checkout doesn't support 'Transfer Shipping Options' so it fallbacks to the old style. It should be easy to reproduce with any other Paypal Express SDK too. We are able to consistently isolate this across multiple environments. Now I need to wash my hands.. eek magento & magento clients..